# Community wiki checkbox doesn't show warning on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, community-wiki

I just wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952828/1871033) on my phone and was surprised to see it as community wiki afterwards.

I must have accidentally tapped the checkbox that is right above the submit button.

Now the issue is, there was no warning displayed.

If I switch to desktop mode, it works:

[image]

But on mobile, there is no confirmation:

[image]

Comment: Little known fact. You can use desktop features in mobile. Scroll down to the  bottom of the page. Click **Enable Responsiveness**.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't work for me though. The site behaves exactly the same either way (non-responsive). (Yes I have not enabled desktop mode but just clicked the "full site" link.)

Comment: ... Oh it seems when I am on a user profile, it doesn't work, but on the question list it does...

Comment: After "full site"> "Enable responsiveness"

Comment: Yes that's what I did but the issue was that I was on a user profile page and apparently these are not responsive even with "enable responsiveness" on

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We're actively looking at how mobile views are working on the site, and this is part of it. When we revisit this, we'll have more updates on this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

It looks like the dialog was just never implemented on mobile.  It was nestled in the editor initialization code and we don't initialize the full editor for mobile views.

Comment: I see it's fixed. Thank you!